# Implementing a Soundboard App with Microphone Input

Tags: windows, microphone, audio-processing

I'm currently working on a project and I'm seeking some guidance on how to implement a soundboard application that utilizes the microphone input. The goal is to play music or audio through the microphone so that it can be broadcasted to platforms like Discord. However, I'm facing some challenges in understanding how to achieve this.

Here's an overview of what I'm trying to accomplish:

- Create a Windows soundboard application.
- Use the microphone as the audio source.
- Play music or audio files through the microphone input in real-time.
- Ensure that the audio output can be used in other applications, such as Discord voice chats.

Here are some specific questions I have:

- What programming languages and libraries would be most suitable for this task?
- How can I access the microphone input and route audio through it?
- Are there any existing tutorials or examples that can help me get started?

I have some experience with programming, but audio processing is relatively new to me, so any guidance or advice on where to begin would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, probably your question doesn't meet Stack Overflow requirements. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)